# How to create dynamic navigation menu select from database using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been trying to find the solution for creating a dynamic navigation menu store in database using Codeigniter. But till now I can't solve my problem and I really don't understand how to create this feature I try to create below code but I can show only menu without sub menu.
As in the view I can't only select menu but can't with sub menus. I'm really don't understand how to make the conditional for create sub menus
Because I have to compared **parent** with menus **ID** if I found the **parent** equal to menu **ID** I will show the drop down for current that menu
But it is fail for me

***Here is my View***

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a>some menu retrieve from DB </a></li>
           <li class="dropdown megamenu-fullwidth"> 
              <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">title</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                <li class="megamenu-content">
                 <ul class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                   <li class="no-border"><p><strong>Head</strong></p></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Descript<br></a></li>
                 </ul> 
               </li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
       <?PHP endif; ?>
      <?PHP endforeach; ?>
 </ul>    
</div>
```

***Here is Controller***

```
$this->data['menus'] =  $this->nav_m->menus();
```

***Here is model***

```
 public function menus() {
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("nav"); 
        $this->q = $this->db->get();
        if ($this->q->num_rows() > 0) {
           return $this->q->result_array();
        }
    }
```

Here is my navigation which I used Var_dump() from DB

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=9)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'uid' => string '0' (length=1)
      'text' => string 'title1' (length=6)
      'link' => string 'menus1' (length=6)
      'show_condition' => string '1' (length=1)
      'parent' => string '0' (length=1)
      'class' => string '' (length=0)
      'data' => string '' (length=0)
      'des' => string '' (length=0)
  1 => 
    array (size=9)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'uid' => string '0' (length=1)
      'text' => string 'title2' (length=6)
      'link' => string 'menus2' (length=6)
      'show_condition' => string '1' (length=1)
      'parent' => string '2' (length=1)
      'class' => string '1' (length=1)
      'data' => string '' (length=0)
      'des' => string '' (length=0)
  2 => 
    array (size=9)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'uid' => string '0' (length=1)
      'text' => string 'title3' (length=6)
      'link' => string 'menu3' (length=5)
      'show_condition' => string '1' (length=1)
      'parent' => string '2' (length=1)
      'class' => string '' (length=0)
      'data' => string '' (length=0)
      'des' => string '' (length=0)
  3 => 
    array (size=9)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'uid' => string '0' (length=1)
      'text' => string 'Sub1' (length=4)
      'link' => string 'menu4' (length=5)
      'show_condition' => string '1' (length=1)
      'parent' => string '2' (length=1)
      'class' => string '' (length=0)
      'data' => string '' (length=0)
      'des' => string '' (length=0)
  4 => 
    array (size=9)
      'id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'uid' => string '0' (length=1)
      'text' => string 'sub2' (length=4)
      'link' => string 'hhhhhhhhhhhh' (length=12)
      'show_condition' => string '1' (length=1)
      'parent' => string '2' (length=1)
      'class' => string '' (length=0)
      'data' => string '' (length=0)
      'des' => string '' (length=0)
  5 =>
```

Please help

Comment: are you allowed to change the information in the database or does it _have_ to stay like that? It would be so much easier if you had one table for your parent menus, and one menu for your children.

Comment: in the first value of your array, you have an array with `parant = 0`, is this suppose to be a parent menu? if so, how would you explain the others, they have `parent = 2`, but there are no parents for those submenus

Comment: should you show me some (sorry) if do like that you will select it and compare on menus ID right

Comment: yes you would just need to get that information from the database by ID

Comment: i'm really crazy right now I have not any idea about this

Comment: if I create two table and compare on ID how can I know which one is submenu of its menu and how can i create code as my html and how to do when i get the value as array and loop throw it

Comment: `id=2` and `parent=2`? for second element?

Comment: I think it may be like this but I don't know how to do code. should you show me some code.

Comment: Add your html code(without php) to the question. how you want ul li with provided data.I think parent should be 0 for title 2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the way you have your result is too complicated to deal with. I would separate children and parent menu items in your database, then build an array so that the view can then parse it easier. Try this:

DB:

[image]

Then your model:

```
function menus() {
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("menu_parents");
    $q = $this->db->get();

    $final = array();
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($q->result() as $row) {

            $this->db->select("*");
            $this->db->from("menu_children");
            $this->db->where("fk_parent_id", $row->parent_id);
            $q = $this->db->get();
            if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
                $row->children = $q->result();
            }
            array_push($final, $row);
        }
    }
    return $final;
}
```

Controller:

```
public function get_menus() {
    $this->load->model('your_model');
    $menus = $this->your_model->menus();
    $data = array('menus' => $menus);
    $this->load->view('page1', $data);
}
```

View:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <?php foreach ($menus as $menu) { ?>
            <li><a><?= $menu->text ?></a></li>
            <?php
            if (isset($menu->children)) {
                foreach ($menu->children as $child) {
                    ?>
                    <li class="dropdown megamenu-fullwidth"> 
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"><</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                            <li class="megamenu-content">
                                <ul class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                                    <li class="no-border"><p><strong>Head</strong></p></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Descript<br></a></li>
                                </ul> 
                            </li> 
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks i have to do it now

Comment: I found one think on menu_childrent if I set value of **fk_parent_id** different (doesn't relate to Parent_id(1,2,3) and fk_parent_id(3,3,3))  I will can't retrieve menu which content parent_id 1 and 2.
How could we selecte all parent_menu although it have not childrent

Comment: in the model, move `array_push($final, $row);` outside and under the `if` statement. I will update my answer.

Comment: my ID: 573 593 595
Password:126khd

Comment: I coun't vote up now sorry because I have not yet enough reputation sorry I will vote letter

Comment: Hi, Are you there? I want to ask how to do if I want to create sub of sub_childrent?